# Customisation of blank tiles in GeoServer

Tags: geowebcache, wmts

I'm trying to find a way how to style blank tiles for WMS in GeoServer that are out of area or zoom level and replace them with images rather than just white blank tiles?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: There is a "default" tile that you can place if the requested tile is missing.  I typically put in an "all black" tile which will be transparent, so the background map tile is displayed.

Comment: @CaryH, thank you for your response, it's not missing, just there is no data for the requested area in PostgreSQL, 
anyway default tile looks interesting to me for other issues, where is this "default" tile property in GeoServer? I was searching and couldn't find anything like this